# ASP.NET Core MVC session same site URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, session-cookies

I have 2 ASP.NET Core MVC apps running on difference ports on one IP (for example App1: 192.168.0.1:8000 and App2: 192.168.0.1:8001).

After logging in to `App1` and then logging in to `App2`, `App1` will create a new `SessionId` for the next request, so it can't get the old session for auth data.

I am setting it up like this in `startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) 
{
    ....
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });
    ....
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();           
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
     });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) 
{
    ....    
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseSession();
    ....
}
```

Comment: Try to use difference name for both `CookieSession` and `CookieAuthentication` please, your two app might overriding each others same cookies.

Comment: @GordonKhanhNg. yes, I have just found out of it and go back here to see your answer, thanks anyway :)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that I didn't set the cookie name for each App, so it's overwrite each other cookie like @GordonKhanhNg. have just said.

```
services.AddSession(options => {
    ....
    options.Cookie.Name = ".App1.Session";
    ....
});
```